# Second Series solution y(2) for Frobenius Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, boundary-value-problem

I am currently solving the Frobenius Method for the question $xy'' +y = 0$  given the ICs $y(0) = 0, y'(0)=1$

I have done some work into solving that the first series solution for $y_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n x^{n+1} \over (n+1)!(n)!}$

I am just completely stuck now at working out the second series solution for $y_2$

I've figured out that the we use the smaller root of the indicial equation $r(r-1)=0 \rightarrow{r=0}$

and that by plugging this into the recurrence relation, we get $a_0 =0$ (which can't be the case)

But from here I am just stuck, could someone help me out please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is the right indicial equation. And yes, it is x not x^2, I just wanted to help on how to find the second series solution